# Pay team mates out of revenues on my name

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am working on a software project which will generate money through ads. The ads company has my tax info and will provide information about the revenues generated though ads to IRS.

On the project, I work with two other people from outside US and we'll split the profits generated from ads.

Can I deduct the money that I giving to my team mates from the taxes that I pay? If yes, how should I record the transaction?

PS: We don't have any partnership or something similar, it is just each of us on his own.

Comment: What are the expected earnings/year? US$100? US$1,000?  US$100,000?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I deduct the money that I giving to my team mates from the taxes
>   that I pay? If yes, how should I record the transaction?

Why? Why are you giving money to your team mates? That's the most important question, and any answer without taking this into account is not full. You would probably have to talk to a professional tax adviser (a CPA/EA licensed in your state) about the details, but in general - you cannot deduct money you give someone just because you feel like it. Moreover, it may be subject to an additional tax - the gift tax.

> PS: We don't have any partnership or something similar, it is just
>   each of us on his own.

*Assuming* you want to give your team mates money because you **developed the project together** - then you do in fact have a partnership. In order to split the income *properly*, you should get a tax ID for the partnership, and issue a 1065 and K-1 for each team mate. In most states, you don't need to "register" a partnership with the state. Mere "lets do things together" creates a partnership.

Otherwise, if they work **for** you (as opposed to *with you* in the case above), you can treat it as your own business income, and pay your team mates (who are now your contractors/employees) accordingly. Be careful here, because the difference between contractor and employee in tax law is significant, and you may end up being on the hook for a lot of things you're not aware of.

Bottom line, in certain situation you cannot deduct, in others you can - you have to discuss it with a professional. Doing these things on your own without fully understanding what each term means - is dangerous, and IRS doesn't forgive for "honest mistakes".

Comment: this is beyond my level of expertise, but my guess is that the rules for contractor vs employee are different if the employee/contractor is outside the US. I would think the IRS would have little incentive to care what a foreigner working in another country is classified as. No taxes to collect one way or another.

Comment: @stoj oh, there's so much beyond a simple logic. There are tax treaties, there's "effectively connected income" issues, there's domestic partnerships with foreign members and foreign partnerships with domestic members - this could be a can of worms on such a magnitude that you can't even start to imagine. Otherwise it would be a trivial tax evasion scheme - get a foreign friend to write all the money on his name - and voila, no taxes. Doesn't work this way.

Comment: There is a threshold for gift tax, I seem to recall it is around $10,000 per recipient per year.  So for small transfers there is no gift tax.  On the other hand, it might not be a gift, it might be income.

Comment: @Paul well, it depends on the situation. I doubt we're talking about a case of unconditional love here.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:  This is not professional tax advice.**  If you think you need professional tax advice, find a licensed professional in your local area.

What are the expected earnings/year? US$100? US$1,000?  US$100,000?  I would say if this is for US$1,000 or less that registering an EIN, and consulting a CPA to file a Partnership Tax return is not going to be a profitable exercise.... all the earnings, perhaps more, will go to paying someone to do (or help do) the tax filings.

The simplest taxes are for a business that you completely own.  Corporations and Partnerships involve additional forms and get more and more and complex, and even more so when it involves foreign participation.  Partnerships are often not formal partnerships but can be more easily thought of as independent businesses that each participants owns, that are simply doing some business with each other.

[Schedule C is the IRS form you fill out for any businesses that you own](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sc.pdf%E2%80%8E). On schedule C you would list the income from advertising.  Also on schedule C there is a place for all of the business expenses, such as ads that you buy, a server that you rent, supplies, employees, and independent contractors.  Amounts paid to an independent contractor certainly need not be based on hours, but could be a fixed fee, or based on profit earned.

Finally, if you pay anyone in the USA over a certain amount, you have to tell the IRS about that with a Form 1099 at the beginning of the next year, so they can fill out their taxes.

BUT.... according to an article in [International Tax Blog](http://intltax.typepad.com/intltax_blog/2012/10/form-1099-for-payments-to-foreign-contractors-for-services.html) you might not have to file Form 1099 with the IRS for foreign contractors if they are not US persons (not a US citizen or a resident visa holder).

Comment: This is not exactly the situation here. I'm guessing that the "foreign contractor" is not in fact a contractor but an employee/partner. If so, your answer is not applicable.

Comment: I would say if A, B, and C develop a web site together without any written agreement, but A registers as the owner for paypal or other revenue sources for profiting from the website, and A pays the costs of hosting and can turn it on and off at will, then the relationship between A, B, and C might not be a partnership.  The idea that B or C have any ownership in this thing is tenuous at best.  B and C can think they are partners when in fact they are not.

Comment: I would argue that in this case if A abuses the agreement he may end up legally and criminally liable, but it doesn't dissolve the agreement. A paying the hosting costs may add to his partnership basis (i.e.: decrease his personal taxable portion of the income), but it doesn't change the fact that the partnership exists.

Comment: I added a paragraph to address the approximate costs of dealing with partnership taxation.